# changing some words in URL like ' ?author , ?cat , in WORDPRESS (HOW?)

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the word this in the url

in category : `http://www.example.com/?cat=USA`

I want it to be like this `http://www.example.com/?section=USA`

also, from author I want to change it to seller
`http://www.example.com/?author=1` to

`http://www.example.com/?seller=1`

How ?

Comment: change the url .. Look at this website .. it use wordpress .. the link of author like this http://www.tech-wd.com/wd/author/saud-hawawi/ .. I want to change 'author' word to 'seller' ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you just use the custom permalinks like
 `/seller/admin` for author
`section/usa` for the category

Comment: ok can you mark the answer right so i can get points... thanks

Answer (score 0):

use your .htacess for that
mode rewrite

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php